# Fixed sidebar with Skeleton responsive layout

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-position, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I have a simple two column responsive design with Skeleton boilerplate.
For the sidebar I have this *div*, inside a *container div*:

```html
 <div class="container">
    <div class="four columns">
       /* logo and menu */
    </div>
    <div class="nine columns post">
       /* contents... */
    </div>
 </div>
```

I like the way it looks in wide viewports and how it's stacked on narrower ones, but I'd like to have the sidebar (*four columns div*) in the wider sizes always fixed at the left, while scrolling the content of the other *div*.

Tried several things but it ends screwing up the responsive layout, I guess I don't have a thorough knowledge of CSS positioning...

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: Actually what you want to do? I think you want to do the given div are remain constant when you scroll the website. If you want this, it is possible to do.

Comment: Exactly, the "four columns" div to remain static at the left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I read that you are using the Skeleton Boilerplate.

I recommend that you put your logo and menu in a `<nav>`element. When closing `</nav>`, insert a non-breaking space (`&nbsp;`). This non-breaking space will hopefully fix your problem!

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="four columns">
       <nav>
       /* logo and menu */
       </nav>
       &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="nine columns post">
    /* contents... */
    </div>
```

The next thing to do is to go to your CSS file and insert:

```
nav{ position:fixed; width:220px; /*found the width-info on Skeleton website*/ }
```

Let me know if it worked out for you!

Comment: Excellent, thanks! Now I guess just have to adjust for the smaller viewports.

Comment: Yeah, this solution breaks the responsiveness. I'd love to see your final solution, Christian.

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to have a "sticky" div

Try using [waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/)

Comment: I'm trying that like here: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-tutorials/create-a-sticky-navigation-header-using-jquery-waypoints/
to trigger this class on the sidebar when scrolling: 
    .sticky {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
    }

But then the sidebar gets on top and the content under it, left-aligned as if the sidebar (.four column div) had dissapeared :(