# How to create fixed sidebar with Skeleton CSS?

Tags: html, css, sidebar, skeleton-css-boilerplate

This question was asked about [a few years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190320/fixed-sidebar-with-skeleton-responsive-layout) with no acceptable answers. I would like to know if things have changed and it is now possible to use [Skeleton CSS](http://getskeleton.com) with a fixed, responsive sidebar. Preferably without the need for Javascript.

My HTML is as follows:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skeleton.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
  </head>
  <body class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <section class="three columns">
        <nav id="sidebar">
          sidebar content ...
        </nav>
        &nbsp;
      </section>
      <section id="content" class="nine columns">
        body content ...
      </section>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've tried a few different ways in CSS to make the sidebar fixed (doesn't scroll), but keeping the layout responsive to size changes. The simplest is the following in `custom.css`:

```
#sidebar {
  position: fixed;
}
```

This looks right until the page becomes too narrow, and then the sidebar and body content overlap although what they should do instead is the sidebar would be above the body content.

Here is a [jsfiddle page](https://jsfiddle.net/27wmryqk/2/) that one can play with for this problem.

How do I create a proper, fixed sidebar with Skeleton CSS that behaves properly to window size changes?

Comment: Not sure how much of a "Skeleton-CSS fix" it is, but to fix the overlapping issue you had you should just be able to add "z-index: 9999;" to the #sidebar ID and you should be good

Comment: dont know much about "Skelton-CSS" but you can add media queries to fix for different window sizes

Comment: @Xariez `z-index` indicates the z-order of display for elements, but won't stack the two elements one above (as opposed to on top of) another when the viewport is too narrow, right?

Comment: @rityzmon Not entirely sure about that actually. It should still work but, I haven't had the use nor experience too much myself with z-index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use "media query to change the behavior of the CSS when display is less then 480 in it's width:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #sidebar{
        position: relative;
    }
}

#sidebar{
  position: fixed;
}
```

Using it this way, it will be relative to whatever if width is less then 480px, or fixed on higher resolution.

Comment: Thanks. I added the `@media` query as you indicated but the page doesn't do anything different. Do I have to do something to enable media queries?

Comment: Never mind, I didn't realize but my browser window doesn't resize below 500px, so it didn't trigger. Thanks.

Comment: Also, I had to have the media query *below* the regular CSS to make it trigger properly. Is this supposed to be the case?

Answer (score 1):

A comment to Guy Dafnys answer:

Since skeleton has a "mobile first" approach I think it would be better to do it this way:

```
#sidebar{
  position: relative;
}

@media (min-width: 550px) { /*Skeletons default grid-activation width*/
  #sidebar{
    position: fixed;
    max-width: 18%; /*Avoids overlapping*/
  }
}
```